# Angular 2, Unable to iterate through array

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, rxjs

I have a subscribed to a FirebaseObjectObservable to get value of a property of an object from my firebase database. This property can contain multiple values so I stored the values in a local array variable.

But I am unable to iterate through this local array variable using forEach. So I console.log this array variable. This variable seems to have json format maybe thats why I am unable to iterate. Please help me find a way to iterate through this variable.

*** Code and Console Images :**

[Code Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KXvWF.png)

[Console Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H4gxi.png)

*** Edit  ***

I shifted the code inside the subscribe method to iterate.

```
getAttachments() {
this.assignment.subscribe(asnDetails => {
  if (asnDetails.fileKey) {
    this.fileKeys.push(asnDetails.fileKey);
    this.fileKeys[0].forEach(asnFileKey => {  // <---- shifted this forEach loop inside subscribe 
      this.asnFiles = this._getAsnService.getAssignmentFiles(asnFileKey);
      this.asnFiles.subscribe(file => {
        this.fileNames.push(file.name);
      });
    });
  }
});
}
```

Comment: Please put the relevant code in the question. Also, please write in correct international English, in which the word "I" is capitalized. Finally, please spare us unnecessary details about where you are in your learning curve, or how grateful you are for future answers.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Answer (score 2):

The `this.fileKeys` value is available only within the `subscribe` handler. That's basic to asynchronous programming. Your console log is immediately after the subscribe, and is executed before the subscription has had a change to fire.

Answer (score 1):

You have one nested array in your screenshot. The first one is of length 1 and the nested one is of length two. So you can access `array[0].forEach(item => console.log(item))`

Comment: `this.fileKeys[0].forEach( item => {
      console.log(item);
    });` tried this just now, got this error : Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined
TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined
    at ....

Answer (score 0):

Sadly, I can't comment. It's not an angular or firebase problem.
It's a normal array, based on your console screenshot.
Have you tried to iterate through `this.fileKeys`?
If someone could post this as a comment, I would delete this as an answer.

Comment: yes i tried iterating this.fileKeys but it seems like its not entering the loop.   
    `this.fileKeys.forEach( x => {
      console.log("Iterating...");
    }); `

Comment: Can you do a `console.log(this.fileKeys.length))` please and post the result?

Comment: `console.log(this.fileKeys.length)` returns 0

Comment: and 1 if used inside the subscribe